# SetTimeout doesn't work on first time in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, web

I wanted to add a hover delay on dropdown menu link, that after a 1sec it opens another dropdown with another links, it adds a class with `display:block` on hover. My js code works fine, **except!** it won't display another submenu on the first time.

Scenario:

1. Entering the page
2. Hover on menu to see submenu
3. Hover on submenu link to see another submenu, it should show after a 1 second
4. It doesn't show
5. Repeat point 3. and it actually works.

```
 const flyoutSubEl = this.el.querySelector(`[${this.options.megaMenuSubId}='${flyoutSubId}']`);
        const flyoutSubTriggerEl = this.el.querySelector(`[${this.options.megaMenuSubTrigger}='${flyoutSubId}']`);

        if (flyoutSubEl.classList.contains(this.options.menuActive)) {
            if (this.eventTrigger == 'click') {
                this._closeAllFlyoutsSub();
            }
        } else {
            let timer;
            flyoutSubTriggerEl.addEventListener("mouseenter",()=>{
                timer = setTimeout(()=>{
                    this._closeAllFlyoutsSub(this.options.menuActive);
                    flyoutSubEl.classList.add(this.options.menuActive);
                }, 500);
            })
            flyoutSubTriggerEl.addEventListener("mouseleave",()=>{
                clearTimeout(timer);
            })
            
        }
```

Does anyone have a clue about why is this code not working on the first time?

Console isn't showing anything useful, if the dropdown should be on display:block from the beginning, then why is this working on second time?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

read something about event loop in js, and I think you can find answer why settimeout didn't work. And to solve your problem try to use transition property. example.

```html
div > ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```